# How can I make a constraint false when another is?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, systems-of-equations

Let us assume that I have some constraints

$$a_i^Tx=b_i, i \in [1, N]$$

Let us assume that the first constraint $a_1^Tx=b_1$ is not satisfied for a given $x$, is there a way I can make the next $N-1$ constraints not satisfied as well?

**In other words:** Is there a way to "link" some constraints together so that they all become false if one of them is false? My idea was to use some binary variables that each of the constraints would "share", but I struggle to have something that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t$ be a binary variable (i.e. values $0$ or $1$).  Then consider the constraints
$t (a_1^T x - b_1) = 0$ and $(a_i^T x - b_i)^2 \ge \varepsilon (1-t)$ for $i \ne 1$, where $\varepsilon$ is a small positive number.  This will work in a discrete situation
where if $(a_i^T x - b_i)^2$ is not $0$ it can be bounded away from $0$.
"Not equal" constraints can't be easily dealt with (either theoretically or practically) in the continuous case.